# Is there an R function for including column into row data

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to perform chi-square test in R by transform data frame from csv file using R from the following structure

```
Observed Values        East  West   North   South
Males                  50    142    131     70  
Females                435   1523   1356    750
```

to

following example

```
Row Observed value      Region 
1   1                   East
2   1                   East
3   1                   East
...
435 0                   East
```

Given that 1 = male. 0 = female

I been trying to use stack and data frame function to create the new table using R. I need the following table to perform chi-square test in R. The code I am trying is as below:

```
Stacked_data <- stack(data)
library(dummies)
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:0, Observed.Values )
df2 <- cbind(Stacked_data, dummy(df1$id, sep = "_"))
```

Expected result will contain 2 column (observed value and region). Observed value will contain the categorical value for male = 1, and female = 0.Region will contain the region for respective observed value.

So that when i perform

```
table(Region,Observed Values)
```

It will produce

```
            Observed Values
Region         1      0
  East        50    435
  West       142   1523
  North      131   1356
  South       70    750
```

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code or data (e.g., `dput(head(x))` or `data.frame(...)`) directly.

Comment: `data.frame(id=1:0, Obs)` makes no sense to me: the first column has two values (1 and 0, decreasing), and we can only infer that the second has many more. I don't see how the data in image1 (with a sum of 4,457) can be transformed into a column of 0s and 1s with 436 rows. And since you don't provide any definition for `dummy` (not sure it's `lme4::dummy`, as that one doesn't have `sep=` argument), it's unclear what you are really doing there. Lacking any feedback, I'm voting to close as *unclear what you're asking* (could also be *"why isn't this code working"*).

Comment: I am trying to create a dummy_variable  to replace male = 1 and female = 0 by using the dummy function from library dummies.

Comment: Formatting a question well can make it easier for readers to quickly parse the important parts. I suggest you quickly look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting. (And apologies on `dummies::dummy`, I skipped that before, you did have it the first time.)

Comment: May i know how do you actually format the table because i do not seen such information in the link .

Comment: It's fine-enough for now, thanks, I edited your question to format it as "code". The only change I'd do is take the space out of the first column. As long as there are no embedded spaces (in a column name or cell value), then I can copy that with `ctrl-c`, then use `read.table(header=TRUE, "clipboard")` to bring it into R as a frame. If it is not in a "code" block (preformatted, fixed-width), then it takes a bit more work to do that. Key: making it easy for people to play with your sample data makes it much more likely you'll get constructive comments and/or answers.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely read more on how to format table and syntax highlighting before posting in SO. I will also try to understand your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: based on your expected output, you don't need much at all. Using `obs` from below, all you need to get your output (on which you can run `chisq.test`) is:

```r
obs2 <- t(obs[,-1])
dimnames(obs2) <- list(Region = rownames(obs2), Observed = c('0', '1'))
obs2
#        Observed
# Region    0    1
#   East   50  435
#   West  142 1523
#   North 131 1356
#   South  70  750
```

But, then again, if all you need is to run a `chisq.test` on them, it doesn't matter which orientation you use:

```r
### original frame you provided
chisq.test(obs[,-1])
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test
# data:  as.matrix(obs[, -1])
# X-squared = 1.5959, df = 3, p-value = 0.6603

### transposed/re-labeled frame
chisq.test(obs2)
#   Pearson's Chi-squared test
# data:  obs2
# X-squared = 1.5959, df = 3, p-value = 0.6603
```

No difference. Perhaps all you needed was the `[,-1]` part?

---

Here's an attempt, though I don't know that it's exactly what you expect. (Input data is at the bottom of this answer.)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out1 <- obs %>%
  gather(Region, v, -Observed) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do( tibble(Region = .$Region, Observed = rep(1L * (.$Observed == "Males"), .$v)) ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(Row = row_number())

out1
# # A tibble: 4,457 x 3
#    Region Observed   Row
#    <chr>     <int> <int>
#  1 East          1     1
#  2 East          1     2
#  3 East          1     3
#  4 East          1     4
#  5 East          1     5
#  6 East          1     6
#  7 East          1     7
#  8 East          1     8
#  9 East          1     9
# 10 East          1    10
# # ... with 4,447 more rows
```

We can verify that it is reversible with

```r
xtabs(~ Observed + Region, data = out1)
#         Region
# Observed East North South West
#        0  435  1356   750 1523
#        1   50   131    70  142
```

(even if the columns and rows are in a different order as the input, the numbers match).

---

Data:

```r
obs <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Observed        East  West   North   South
Males           50    142    131     70  
Females         435   1523   1356    750 ")
```

Comment: I actually want to perform ```chisq.test(table(Region, Observed Values)``` to get the p-value. I already updated the expected outcome into the question.

Comment: I am ***really*** confused: your expected output is ... your input, transposed, plus "Males --> 1" (etc) ........ ???

Comment: My main objective is to perform chi-square test using the data from csv file. So, I thought maybe I need to create the dummy variable to convert males -> 1 and females -> 0.  Then, combine all column (east, west, south, north ) under a column call Region. Ultimately, perform `chisq.test(table(Region, Observed Values)` for the chi-square test. Please advice me if i can perform chi-square test without having to create a new column called region to include all the column (east, west, south, north).

Comment: Whether you can perform the test without ..., then please read my answer, as I think I show that this can be done easily given the data you said is your input structure, with no data modification/transformation necessary. If your input csv file does not look like the table at the top of your question, however, then we have wasted our time. Please be clear: if your CSV structure is not shown in your question, *then show (a sample of) it*.

Comment: My CSV structure is exactly the same as first table above with 2 row and 4 columns.

Comment: Then indeed most of this has been an exercise in "unnecessary". Just run `chisq.test(x)`.

Comment: I need to transform the data frame before i can use chisq.test(x), where x is the data from csv. I get the following error if not using any transformation. ```
all entries of 'x' must be nonnegative and finite ```

Comment: `chisq.test(x[,-1])`? If anything from `sapply(obs, is.character)` is true (other than the first column "Observed"), then your problem is 100% how you read it in (for that, realize that how data is shown on the console does not clearly show what is stored internally; please include the output from `dput(obs)` if this *still* does not work).

Comment: I get same p-value (0.66) by performing chisq.test(x[,-1]) . I guess i do not need to do any transformation after all. Sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: Not to be petty ... but can you accept the answer anyway (and even upvote it)?

Comment: Done. Thanks for your patient and time.

Comment: This highlights that sometimes we don't know how to ask questions well, and I know I've fallen prey to it myself. The key is be about as honest as you can be with input and your eventual expectations. In this case, knowing you needed to run `chisq.test` on it would have cleared up a lot, much earlier. Often, the real problem is not what is asked, so knowing more up-front helps, and the dialog in comments often points to the real culprit. Good luck!